# See list of users who have viewed a document in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I am looking for a way to see what users (if any) have viewed a particular document in google docs? I know that there is a revision history, but is it possible to see which users have viewed it without making any changes?

The only thing that I can see that is somewhat relevant is the ability to sort documents by 'Last Viewed' which obviously shows the last viewer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can turn on analytics support and try to associate a viewer to an IP address

Comment: Cheers for the idea. I will do this, however I'm not sure how easy it will be to associate ip addresses as the document has multiple collaborators.

Answer (score 6):

No, this feature does not exist in GoogleDocs

[Google Support Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=5af30bc2edfaf0f5&hl=en)

Comment: Explain the downvote? The feature is not officially supported. Analytics can help, but, if you have more then a few users it probably won't be useful and requires guess work.